# Use previous output for next command in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, output

I want to use output for next command, so I find ZIP files on DESKTOP with:

```
dir [DESKTOP PATH] /b /s /a-d | findstr .zip
```

so.. output is ZIP DESTINATION :

```
C:\Users\[Profile]\Desktop\forexample.zip
C:\Users\[Profile]\Desktop\forexample2.zip
```

and I use special software with cmd option to delete files with *.exe extension inside ZIP using this command :

```
zip [ZIP DESTINATION] -d *.exe
```

Is it posible to USE first output for next command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can use :

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s /a-d %userprofile%\desktop\*.zip') do zip %%i -d *.exe
```